# Calculating the flow of a vectorfield (with parametrization)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

I have received a solution for the question below,
 it is solved with the `divergence theorem` and `cylindrical coordinates`.
 However, I was wondering if it is possible to solve it with `parameterization`.
 Is this possible?
[image]

The image below is a demonstration on how I attempted to solve this problem with parametrization.
[image]

Comment: To avoid downvotes you should note that users on MSE prefer formatting in [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) rather than including an image.

Comment: (1) Show some effort, (2) Write down the "given solution", perhaps doing the work in that.